# Check if the window, and if so, change to document in jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jkey

I have a plugin, jKey, and people kept reporting IE bugs that it didnt work. The bug isn't with my script, or jQuery, but rather IE doesn't support window keypresses. I want to "auto-correct" this by checking if the `$(window)` was selected (which i did below by check, if "`this`" has a `parentNode`) and if it was i want to switch `this` to `document`.

I'm having no luck tho. I keep getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

I've tried:

```
if($(this)[0].parentNode == undefined){
    $(this) = $(document);
}
```

And:

```
if($(this)[0].parentNode == undefined){
    this = document;
}
```

Any ideas? Also, if you have a better way of checking for the `window` please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$` is a function. `$(this)` is a function invocation. You cannot assign a value to a function invocation.
- `this` *never* directly assignable.
- Are you really jQuery-ifying `this` and then immediately unwrapping it?

  ```
  $(this)[0].parentNode
  // is exactly equivalent to
  this.parentNode
  ```

> Also, if you have a better way of checking for the window please let me know!

In the plugin, alias `this` to a keyword that you *can* assign. A frequent choice is `self`:

```
// plugin entry point
var self = this;

// use self instead of this throughout the rest of the plugin
```

Now you actually can change the "scope:"

```
if (!this.parentNode) {
    self = document;
}
```

---

> your snippet seems to convert all selections to document? not just window? so `$('input')` is converted to document

Oh, right, you're talking about a jQuery plugin. `this` is probably already a jQuery object, in which case `this.parentNode` would always be a falsy value. You can either unwrap it:

```
if (!this[0].parentNode) {
    self = $(document);
}
```

or use

```
if (this.first().parent().length) {
    self = $(document);
}
```

Comment: that's incorrect. $(this) returns an array. If you do this.parentNode you get undefined for everything. If you do $(this)[0] you get a variation of results from null to undefined.

Also, about the function, im just out of ideas. Ive tried everything

Comment: also your snippet seems to convert all selections to document? not just window? so $('input') is converted to document :(

Comment: Since you're talking about a jQuery plugin, it sounds like `this` is already a jQuery object. You can either unwrap it (e.g. `this[0].parentNode`) or use `this.first().parent().length`

Comment: _"Also, about the function, im just out of ideas. Ive tried everything"_ - use the aliasing method I described.

Comment: As I said, your script converts everything to document, including DOM elements. After I did this though it worked: `var self = this;
  if($(self)[0].parentNode == undefined){
    self = document;
  }` Thanks!

Comment: Like I just commented, it sounds like `this` refers to a jQuery object, which is why `this.parentNode` would always be a falsy value.

Comment: @Oscar For future reference, `$` doesn't return an array. It returns an array like object. Don't get the two mixed up.

Comment: @Matt You would need to do `self = $(document)`, because this would be wrapped, meaning the document needs to be as well.

Comment: @Matt I know what you mean. xD